# Socket.io Failed to load resource

Tags: node.js, resources, load, websocket, socket.io

i have error

```
 Failed to load resource http://localhost:3250/socket.io/1/?t=1376856906369
```

when i try do something with socket.io (loading work properly)

it is my first lines server

```
        var express = require('express')
      , http = require('http')
      , mysql = require('mysql');

    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


    server.listen(8080);

    app.set('view engine', 'swig');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are starting the server on port 8080, but you are trying to get socket.io from port 3250. So you either need to change this line:

```
//server.listen(8080);
server.listen(3250);
```

...or you use "`http://localhost:8080`" or just "`http://localhost`" in your browser.